# cmd.exe pops up new window when python subcommand.Popen calls script in different directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, subprocess, popen

What specific syntax changes or config changes need to be made so that the entire output from calling the Python 3.7.7 scripts below from `cmd.exe` in Windows 10 will be output into the same single `CMD.exe` window?

The problem below is that the lowest level script ( `someCommand.py` ) triggers its own console window to be launched with its output and then closes as soon as it is done running, so that the output from the lowest level script ( `someCommand.py` ) is not returned to the `cmd.exe` console window that calls it.

---

**The High Level Calling Command**

---

Here is the command run in the `cmd.exe` window to call the high level script:

```
python topLevelScript.py "firstInputsPath"  "secondInputsPath"
```

---

**The Script Called By High-Level Command**

---

Here are the contents of `topLevelScript.py`

```
print("Inside topLevelScript.py script.")

import sys 
import sharedFunctions as sharedfunc

pathToInputs1 = str(sys.argv[1])
pathToInputs2 = str(sys.argv[2])

pathToCalls = "C:\\some\\path\\"
commandToCalls = "someCommand.py"

print ('pathToInputs1:', pathToInputs1 )
print ('pathToInputs2:', pathToInputs2 )

sharedfunc.applyFoundation(commandToCalls, pathToCalls, pathToInputs1, pathToInputs2)
```

---

**A Shared Functions Module Called As 2nd Level**

---

`sharedFunctions.py` is located in the same directory as `topLevelScript.py`, which is also the same directory from which the call to `topLevelScript.py` was made by `cmd.exe` above.  The contents of `sharedFunctions.py` are:

```
import subprocess

def applyFoundation(scriptName, workingDir, inputs1Path, inputs2Path ):
    print("Inside sharedFunctions.py script and applyFoundation(..., ...) function. ")
    print ('inputs1Path:', inputs1Path )
    print ('inputs2Path:', inputs2Path )
    print("scriptName is: " +scriptName)
    print("workingDir is: " +workingDir)

    proc = subprocess.Popen( scriptName,cwd=workingDir,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    while True:
      line = proc.stdout.readline()
      if line:
        thetext=line.decode('utf-8').rstrip('\r|\n')
        decodedline=ansi_escape.sub('', thetext)
        print(decodedline)
      else:
        break
```

---

**The Lowest Level Script, Which is Wrongly Outputting To A New cmd.exe Window:**

---

All of the above prints its console output in the same `cmd.exe` window that called it, except for the output of the `subprocess.Popen(...)` command from above, which launched the following `someCommand.py` and printed its output in a new child `cmd.exe` window which it launched and then destroyed quickly without recording any of its output:

```
print("Inside someCommand.py script. ")

import os 
import subprocess

subprocess.run("some cli command", shell=True, check=True)
```

Note that `someCommand.py` is also located in a different path/directory than both the calling scripts in addition to simply being called by `subprocess.Popen(...)`

> **What specific changes need to be made so that the output from `someCommand.py` will be printed in the same `cmd.exe` console window that calls the higher level parent `topLevelScript.py` and `sharedFunctions.py` programs?**

---

**@Gerrat 's suggestion**

---

Per @Gerrat 's suggestion below, I changed the `subprocess.Popen(...)` line to read as follows instead:

```
mycommand = workingDir+scriptName
cp = subprocess.run(mycommand, shell=True, check=True, capture_output=True, universal_newlines=True)
print(cp.stdout)
```

But I am still seeing the same problem of a new console window being created and destroyed for the lowest level script without passing any of its output to the persistent calling window.

Answer (score 0):

Given that `subprocess.run` returns a [CompletedProcess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CompletedProcess),
I would think that you could just change `someCommand.py` as follows:

```
cp = subprocess.run("some cli command", shell=True, check=True, capture_output=True, universal_newlines=True)
print(cp.stdout)
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and reported the results at the end of the OP.  Note that I had to add the working directory argument.  What else could I try?

Comment: I might have not understood your question, or maybe you didn't understand my suggestion.  I didn't say to change the `subprocess.Popen`, but rather the signature of the `subprocess.run` in your: `Lowest Level Script`